# Why use procs instead of methods?

Tags: ruby, proc-object

I'm new to programming, and ruby is my first real run at it.  I get blocks, but procs seem like a light method/function concept -- why use them?  Why not just use a method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proc is a callable piece of code. You can store it in a variable, pass as an argument and otherwise treat it as a [first-class value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen).

> Why not just use a method?

Depends on what you mean by "method" here.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "hello"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
```

In this code snippet usage of method `bar` is pretty limited. You can call it, and that's it. However, if you wanted to store a reference to it (to pass somewhere else and there call it), you can do this:

```
f = Foo.new
bar_method = f.method(:bar)
```

Here `bar_method` is very similar to lambda (which is similar to Proc). `bar_method` is a first-class citizen, `f.bar` is not.

For more information, read [the article](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas) mentioned by @minitech.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. `'s'.method(:size)` can be stored in a variable, passed as an argument, and otherwise treated as a first class value but it is a method while not being a Proc.

Comment: For me it is usually more about closures or needing a chunk of code that has no need for a `self` (or whose `self` wouldn't be the right thing). The whole Method/Proc/lambda/block thing in Ruby is a bit of a mess IMO. I'm having a hard time thinking of a good answer that wouldn't end up being an entire chapter of a book.

Comment: @muistooshort: you should write a book then and reference it :)

Comment: Thanks guys, this helps get me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

#### *Dispatch table* design pattern example

---

*Why use procs instead of methods?*

- You might want to define one dynamically where the behavior varies
  according to parameters.
- You might want to get a handle on a method
  so you can reference it as data.

A common design pattern involves choosing a method or code block to call based on a runtime value. For example...

```
case 1
  when 0
    p :a
  when 1
    p :b
  when 2
    p :c
end
```

This gets kind of clunky when there are many selectors and there is no way to put the dispatch mechanism together incrementally. So instead something like this can be done:

```
h = [ proc { p :a }, proc { p :b }, proc { p :c } ]

h[1].call
```

You can also use a `Hash` instead of an `Array` if your keys are not a sequence of small integers.  Although the clunky case-selector design pattern occurs frequently in all languages, the dispatch-table-of-procs is rarely used. Usually, it's possible to store the results themselves in the `Array` or `Hash` and then just index them directly. But for something complicated, calling a `proc` allows the most flexibility.

As you proceed in Ruby you will find that this is the reason Ruby has blocks. Blocks are essentially methods that have been passed as a parameter to another method. This is so easy to do in Ruby and Smalltalk that it gets used all the time. You can do the same thing in C but it's too awkward to be any fun and so it is only seen in C when the code writer is losing a desperate battle with complexity.

Comment: I like this but I wouldn't use the position of an array's index for triggering each proc, as tracking that order would be hard to reason about in any sort of big sequence.  I'd link each proc item to a hash key mapping the number.